# Write NSData to a file?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdata

I am trying to write an nsdata to a file on my disk, I have the following code and it doesn't work, am i doing anything wrong?

```
Boolean result = [data writeToFile:@"/Users/aryaxt/Desktop/test2.avi" atomically:YES];
```

test2.avi doesn't exist, I am assuming that writeToFile would create it for me

Comment: On a side note, you should be using `BOOL`, not `Boolean` in Objective-C.

Comment: Try `-[NSData writeToFile:options:error`] (http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-BCIICCHI) and tell us what error is reported.

Comment: (and please verify in the debugger that data is not nil; perhaps the image is also nil ;-)

Comment: I've had the same problem in a multi-threaded application. Use assert([data length] > 0) as a defensive programming style.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try using :

```
NSError *error = nil;
path=@"/Users/aryaxt/Desktop/test2.avi";
[data writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
NSLog(@"Write returned error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
```

That'll tell you why the write is failing.

Comment: `error` should only be examined if the method returns `NO`. Foundation classes may put other objects or fake errors or even garbage in the error argument. (That's not to say that they *do*, but it's part of the programmer contract that they can, so be careful.)

Comment: I have a side question a bit off topic from the documents:Discussion
This method may not be appropriate when writing to publicly accessible files. To securely write data to a public location, use NSFileHandle instead. For more information, seeSecuring File Operations in Secure Coding Guide."
So should I still use it or not ?

Comment: "publicly accessible files"  What does it mean ?

Comment: Many people have upvoted Jonathan's comment about only checking the `error` if the method returns `NO`.  I agree, this is true for released production code, and doubly so when sending the error to the user.  The check was left out here partly for brevity and partly because the `NSLog()` call in this case is used for debugging during development.

Comment: This code is quite old and doesn't take sandboxing into account. Also, check the warnings in Apple's Secure Coding Guide [Race Conditions and Secure File Operations](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/RaceConditions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002585-SW9)